# Get the number of the month in the year by the number of week

Tags: r

I have a column that has number of a week in the year:

```
> merged.tables_d[,"Promo2SinceWeek"]
         Promo2SinceWeek
      1:              NA
      2:              NA
      3:              NA
      4:              NA
      5:              NA
     ---                
1017205:              22
1017206:              22
1017207:              22
1017208:              22
1017209:              22
```

For exemple for the value `22` should be the `5` th month of the year.
So The result should be like this:

```
> merged.tables_d[,"Promo2SinceWeek"]
             Promo2SinceWeek
          1:              NA
          2:              NA
          3:              NA
          4:              NA
          5:              NA
         ---                
    1017205:              5
    1017206:              5
    1017207:              5
    1017208:              5
    1017209:              5
```

How can I do this please?

Comment: Is it possible that some weeks have dates from two different months?

Comment: @www, In this case, we affect the week to the month where it has more days in such month

Comment: I see. Then it is a complicated question because the pattern would be different for each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the lubridate library which makes handling dates easier.

```
library(lubridate)
```

Create dummy data:

```
Promo2SinceWeek <- c(1, 3, 22, 45, 52)
df <- data.frame(Promo2SinceWeek)
```

Return month:

```
month(lubridate::ymd("2017-01-01") + lubridate::weeks(df$Promo2SinceWeek - 1))
```

Not that lubridate::ymd("2017-01-01") specifies the first week of the month of the year you are looking at, in this case 2017.  If your data is from multiple years I would suggest writing a function which changes this value based on another column in your df.

Comment: Smart way to add `weeks` in 1st day of year.

Answer (score 2):

I am not at all sure the code below answers to the question, like @www said in the comments, this varies with the year, but this code does get month 5.
The trick is to create a base date and then set the week with function `lubridate::week`.

```
library(lubridate)

x <- ymd("2018-01-01")
week(x) <- 22
as.integer(format(x, "%m"))
#[1] 5
```

You can make of this code a function, to generalize it to other years.

```
getMonthFromWeek <- function(Week, Year = 2018){
    x <- ymd(paste0(Year, "-01-01"))
    week(x) <- Week
    as.integer(format(x, "%m"))
}

getMonthFromWeek(22)
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Good solution. Another variant of solution can be found by finding date of `1st` day of a week and then evaluate month.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @www and @RuiBarradas that `Year` is needed to convert `Week` into month.

I find `base R` functions more powerful than `lubridate` to handle dates in term of week and week day.

I have used `%W` from `strptime` format as it deals with `UK` format. (`Monday` as 1st day of week). Alternatively `%U` can be used for `US` format (`Sunday` as 1st day of week).

The approach is simple. Take `Year` and `Week` to find 1st day of that week number in that year. One can find month easily once date has been found.

```
#Data
merged.tables_d <- data.frame(sl = 1:6,
                              Promo2SinceWeek = c(4, 14, 22, 24, 30, 35))

# Add another column as month
merged.tables_d$month = as.character(as.Date(
          paste(1,merged.tables_d$Promo2SinceWeek,"2018",sep = "/"),"%u/%W/%Y"),
           "%m")


merged.tables_d
#  sl Promo2SinceWeek month
#1  1               4    01
#2  2              14    04
#3  3              22    05
#4  4              24    06
#5  5              30    07
#6  6              35    08
```